# How to enable developer mode to install apps via ADB for this cheap Android Watch?

Tags: usb-debugging, android-wear, developer-options

I just bought one of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MTB017K):

[image]

It was fairly cheap so, unsurprisingly, in "Settings" I don't see any way to select "developer mode".

How can I go about enabling developer mode (USB debugging) to install apps via ADB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its an Android Wear watch (and it seems so) there is no options on the watch directly. It depends on the phone it is paired with, and all the options are available on your phone.

I have a Moto360 and I also don't have any developer options on my watch. If you plan to develop for Android Wear, you need to install everything on your phone, which will push all needed resources to your watch.

Comment: Sounds promising (+1). Can you tell/provide a link to how to go about it? Thanks

Comment: All info is surely here: http://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html because its the official site, but I have this info from some presentations that i attended so that I don't have a fixed link to this info.

Comment: Is there any chance that you could upload it to some free file sharing site? DropBox woudl be ideal, but anything will do. Thanks

Comment: It was a talk at a conference (droidcon London 2015). Here is the link to the talk https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/6653-android-wear-get-your-app-on-your-wrist but you need to register to watch it.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the steps mentioned here: [Creating and Running a Wearable App](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html).

It's quite similar to the phone : go to **Settings -> About**, then tap on the **Build Number** seven times. It will enable the **Developer Options** where you can enable **ADB Debugging**.

If you can't connect your watch to your computer via USB, you can always enable the Bluetooth debugging following these steps : [Debugging over Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html)

1. Enable **Debug over Blutooth** on Developer Options on the watch
2. Enable **USB Debugging** in the Android Wear app settings on your phone
3. Execute these adb commands :

   ```
   adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
   adb connect localhost:4444
   ```

   If the second command fails, try replacing *localhost* with *127.0.0.1* .

Comment: I changed ADB Debugging to USB debugging. I don't think Developer options has any option named ADB Debugging but USB debugging. Feel free to revert though.

Comment: It's really ADB Debugging on the Developer Options on the watch side. But it's useful only if you can connect your watch to your computer via USB.